# Why is the intersection number $h^2$ equal to the degree of a vector bundle of rank 2?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, sheaf-cohomology

I am trying to understand theory about ruled surfaces and am reviewing **Proposition 3.18** from Arnaud Beauville's book **"Complex Algebraic Surfaces"**:

**Proposition III.18.** Let $S=\mathbb{P}_{C}(E)$ be a geometrically ruled surface
over $C$, $p:S\longrightarrow C$ the structure map. Write $h$ for the class of the sheaf
$\mathcal{O}_S(1)$ in $Pic(S)$ (or in $H^{2}(S,\mathbb{Z})$). Then

1. $Pic(S)=p^{*}(Pic(C))\oplus\mathbb{Z}h$.
2. $H^{2}(S,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}f\oplus\mathbb{Z}h$, where $f$ is the class of a fibre.
3. $h^2=deg(E)$.
4. $[K]=-2h+(deg(E)+2g(C)-2)f$ in $H^{2}(S,\mathbb{Z})$.

My question is in the proof of **statement 3**: It has the exact sequence

$$0\longrightarrow N \longrightarrow p^{*}(E)\longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{S}(1)\longrightarrow 0$$

and from a previous process obtains that $h.[N]=0$. From this exact sequence we obtain an isomorphism $N\otimes\mathcal{O}_{S}(1)=p^{*}(\stackrel{2}\wedge E)$, whence $[N]=-h+p^{*}(e)$, writing $e$ for the class of $\stackrel{2}\wedge E$ in $Pic(C)$. It follows that

$$h^{2}=[N].h+h.p^{*}(e)=h.p^{*}(e)=deg(E)$$

**Could someone help me understand why the last equality $h.p^{*}(e)=deg(E)$?**

Comment: Sections of $\mathcal O_S(1)$ correspond to certain sections $C \to S$, hence $h.f = 1$ for any fiber $f$. On the other hand, $p^*(e)$ is a sum of fiber classes since it is pulled back from $C$. How many fibers? Well, $\deg(e) = \deg(\bigwedge^2 E) = \deg(E)$.